# Draw meshes inside a certain border

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a problem with drawing and adding meshes to the scene inside THREE.JS
I wonder how could I add objects to the 'X' and not the 'Y' area?

[image]

Comment: There is no problem so far, as there is no code provided.

Comment: There's no code to be provided, I said: I just wonder how could I add objects within the boundary of X? If you have any solution I would appreciate to help me.

Comment: So you've tried nothing. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine the origin of the center point of your camera.  This is within the useState() returned object if you look into the actual web inspector console output of your browser.

Then you need to determine the size of your viewport.  This is within the same object output by the useState() console output.

Then you need to determine what boundary you want the line between x and y spaces to be, and generate that using  with the appropriate geometry and material settings.

Then you need to manually do the due dilligence to determine what points are remaining in the x and y areas seperated by your line.  There are a LOT of open ended questions to properly give you a better answer and I agree that you didn't put the blood sweat or tears into figuring this out (or it doesn't seem so from your response), but also understand that learning this stuff can be HARD.

Hope this helps - BotoBilly